# Apply strsplit by conditional

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

I tried to apply the below rules:

*Chop the string by `;` to reach maximum length `n`.*

For example,

```
n <- 4
string <- c("a;a;aabbbb;ccddee;ff")
output <- c("a;a;", "aabb", "bb;", "ccdd", "ee;", "ff")
```

For `"aabb"`, since the chop length `"aabbbb"` exceed `n` = 4, thus we chop by length, `4`.

For `"bb;"`, since the chop length `"bb;"` < 4, we next consider `"bb;ccddee"`. However, the length of next chop exceed 4, and we already have `;` exist in the string. Thus, we chop by `;`.

Currently, I can achieved `or` by using the `Regex`.

```
num <- 4
splitvar <- ";"

## splits pattern
pattern <- paste0("(?<=.{", num, "}|", splitvar, ")")

> pattern
[1] "(?<=.{4}|;)"

string <- c("a;a;aabbbb;ccddee;ff")
strsplit(string, pattern, perl = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "a;"   "a;"   "aabb" "bb;"  "ccdd" "ee;"  "ff"
```

As you can see, we don't actually need to chop `"a;"` and `"a;"`, since the length doesn't exceed the `n` (2 + 2 = 4).

Do anyone have solution on this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex matches either a `splitvar` or a location that is preceded by at least any `num` chars.

The pattern you seek is a regex matching either any one, two or three chars and then a `splitvar` or any `num` chars other than `splitvar` char.

So, you can use

```r
num <- 4
splitvar <- ";"
pattern <- paste0(".{1,", num-1, "}(?:",splitvar,"|$)|[^",splitvar,"]{",num,"}")
pattern ## => .{1,3}(?:;|$)|[^;]{4}
string <- c("a;a;aabbbb;ccddee;ff")
unlist(regmatches(string, gregexpr(pattern, string)))
## => "a;a;" "aabb" "bb;"  "ccdd" "ee;"  "ff"
```

With `stringr`:

```r
library(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(string, pattern))
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/kOF9nj). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IOSuTW/1).

*Details*:

- `.{1,3}(?:;|$)` - one, two, or three chars (other than line break chars if you use `stringr`) as many as possible, and then a `;` char or end of string
- `|` - or
- `[^;]{4}` - any four chars other than a `;` char.